# React Material UI TextField onchange handler continue default action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI `TextField` input, that I want to do something when it changes, without preventing its native handling (without making it controlled input)

```
<TextField onChange={(e)=>{
    something(e.target.value)
    //maybe continueDefault() to make it still accept input
}}/>
```

How can I make it continue its default action, which is to allow it to receive and append text inputs after invoking my `something()` function with the data?

I wanted to allow this without having to make the input a `controlled input`, which is without using a `state` to store its value.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is controlled or uncontrolled input, if you don't call `preventDefault` nothing will prevent that event from happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried your current solution? Passing just the `onChange` property without the `value` doesn't make it a controlled component, which is what you want. There is also no reason to use the hypothetical `continueDefault()`, since `e.preventDefault()` is never called.

Your current solution seems to work fine, and doesn't stop the text field from being further edited.

```js
function something(value) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MaterialUI.TextField
      onChange={(e) => {
        something(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Sorry but I made a mistake when posting, I was using `MUI` `TextField` instead of the native `input`

Comment: @Abraham MaterialUI (MUI) `TextField` seems to behave the same as the native `input`. Are you calling `e.preventDefault()` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use a ref, and ad and event handler. Something like that (untested)

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const onChange = () => {
            something(ref.current.value)
        }
        ref.current.addEventListerner("change", onChange)
        return () => {
            ref.current.removeEventListener("change", onChange)
        }
    })

    return (
        <input ref={ref} />
    )

}
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const onChange = () => {
            something(ref.current.value)
        }
        ref.current.addEventListerner("change", onChange)
        return () => ref.current.removeEventListener("change", onChange)
    })

    return (
        <input ref={ref} />
    )

}
```